# How to create an index in Elasticsearch using elasticsearch-spark?

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-spark

I want to create an index in Elasticsearch from my spark transformation. I wonder what is the best method to do it using the elasticsearch-spark library ?
Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

When writing to the elasticsearch it will create an index if not present

```
df.write
  .format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql")
  .option("es.nodes.wan.only","true")
  .option("es.port","443")
  .option("es.nodes", esURL)
  .mode("Overwrite")
  .save("index/dogs")
```